# White screen on Android Emulator, but screenshot shows it working

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to run a sample Xamarin app and I think my Android emulator is acting up. I've tried enabling Hyper-V, increasing the RAM, telling it to use the host GPU, launching the virtual device from the command line instead of the GUI, and double checking that I have the correct version of the build tools for the version of Android I'm attempting to run.

As a test I've just run the emulator by itself without an app and have discovered that it still shows a white screen even when it is apparently running, somehow. The first image is what I get when I press the Screenshot button. The second image is what I actually see on my desktop. It's been like this for over 10 minutes.

Any advice? I've been Googling like crazy and can't seem to work this out.

[image: Android seemingly running normally] [image: Android emulator not showing anything]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply changing the renderer?

Go on the sidebar menu, click the **3 dots>Settings>Advanced** and try changing the **OpenGL ES Renderer**

Comment: That did the trick; I set the renderer to "SwiftShader" and the API level to "Compatibility" and it runs like a charm.